# Java merging multiple JPEG files into single multi-page TIFF file

Tags: java, tiff, javax.imageio

I have been working for a couple of days now on an program that I am trying to get to separate a multi-page tiff image into single jpeg files, and then remerge multiple jpegs into a single multi-page tiff file for me. I have tried many approaches, mostly ones including the use of the JAI, ImageIO, and custom JAI/ImageIO libraries but I just cant seem to get it to merge 3 single jpeg files into a single TIFF file. For example, I have the following section of code:

```
private void pushTIFF(ArrayList<PlanarImage> images) throws IOException{
        Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("tiff");
        ImageWriter imageWriter = writers.next();

        ImageOutputStream pushOS = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File(pathToTIFF));
        imageWriter.setOutput(pushOS);

        imageWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
        for(int i = 0; i < images.size(); i ++){
            imageWriter.writeToSequence(new IIOImage(images.get(i),null,null),null);
        }
        imageWriter.endWriteSequence();
        imageWriter.dispose();
        pushOS.flush();
        pushOS.close();
    }
```

Where the ArrayList images list is obtained elsewhere by decoding the source multi-page tiff image by using:

```
ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", tiffStream, null)
```

I have also tried other approaches using the ImageIO library instead, but I can't seem to wrap my brain around how to properly approach this problem. Running the method I listed above "pushTiff" seems to always lead to exceptions such as:

```
com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.util.ImagingException: Unable to decode Packbits compressed data - not enough data.
```

As if the three pages obtained earlier are null or something, but when I check that they exist during runtime, they are there.

Basically, I am asking if anyone out there knows of a more up-to-date method of manipulating tiff files in java. In the end, I want to be able to break up a large tiff image into its smaller jpeg pages, and then remerge it into a tiff image that has a smaller overall filesize than what it started with.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this should be reopened, or at least marked as a duplicate of some other question. The linked question does not answer this question, it answers how to READ and DISPLAY, it gives no information on how to WRITE a multi page TIFF.